# How can I use a select like param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use a result from a select in a search param

```
   SELECT distinct policy_business_unit_id as number FROM `policies` WHERE (policy_business_unit_id ='2')
```

That condition shows

```
   number
     2
```

I'm trying to use "2" in my param condition.

```
   SELECT distinct policy_business_unit_id as number FROM `policies` WHERE (policy_business_unit_id ='2')
   SELECT * FROM `cia_ensures` WHERE (id = 2)
```

But i'm getting this

```
 SELECT * FROM `cia_ensures` WHERE (id = NULL)
```

My tables:

```
|cia_ensures|
   |id|  |name|
    1      aaa
    2      bbb
    3      ccc
    ...

|policy_business_units|
   |id|  |name|
    1      abc
    2      def
    3      ghi
    ...

|policies|
   |id|   |number| |policy_business_unit_id|
    1       1234              2
    2       5678              1
    3       9123              2
    4       4567              1      
    ...
```

Here is the controller:

```
   def ajax
     @business = PolicyBusinessUnit.find(:all)
     @select = Policy.find(:all,:select=>['distinct policy_business_unit_id as number'],:conditions=>['policy_business_unit_id = ?',params[:business] ])    
     @list_cias = CiaEnsure.find(:all,:conditions=>['id = ?',@select])
   end
```

Here is the model:

```
   class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :cia_ensure
   end

   class CiaEnsure < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :policies
   end
```

Here is the view:

```
   Business: 
   <%= select_tag "business",options_for_select(@list_cias.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s ,t.id]}, params[:business].to_i ) %>

   Cias:
   <%= select_tag "cias",options_for_select(@business.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s ,t.id]}, params[:cias].to_i ) %>
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
     @business = PolicyBusinessUnit.find(:all)
     @select = Policy.find(:all,:select=>['distinct policy_business_unit_id as number'],:conditions=>['policy_business_unit_id = ?',params[:business] ])    
     @list_cias = CiaEnsure.find(:all,:conditions=>['id = ?',@select[0].try(:number)  ])
```

Here is my logs:

```
   ##### HERE I SHOULD HAVE THE NUMBER 2
   SELECT distinct policy_business_unit_id FROM `policies` WHERE (policy_business_unit_id ='2')

   ##### I WANT TO USE NUMBER 2 
   SELECT * FROM `cia_ensures` WHERE (id = NULL)
```

Please somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you give

```
@list_cias = CiaEnsure.find(:all,:conditions=>['id = ?',@select[0].try(:number)  ])
```

are you sure that `@select[0]` contains an object that responds to `:number` ?

can you provide us the `@select` variable?

PS: If you are using anything newer than `rails 2.3` please restyle you AR queries

Comment: Thanks man , when i tried didn't worked but i restarted my console and now is working. =)
Thanks.